# axios.get() returning data only with special characters in Node.js

Tags: node.js, https, axios, postman, httpresponse

In Node js, trying to fetch data using Axios Get from any URL. For example: [Json Place Holder]
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

.The response.data() is returning special characters. Tried to use the same request from Postman, its fetching data as expected.

In VSCode:

```
const axios = require("axios");
async function getData() {
  const resp = await axios.get(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  {}
 );
 console.log(resp.data);
}
getData();
```

Output:[image: output showing special characters]
I am not sure what went wrong. Node version is v16.14.2, axios version is
^1.2.0

The response' status is 200. the response.data() is as shown in the image. Please help

Comment: code works ok on my side, did you try to run this in shell other than PowerShell (ie. bash)?

Comment: I uninstalled this version of axios and installed an older version v1.1.2. Its working as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298

Answer (score 4):

### In v1.2.1 fixed this error.

You can do it with latest Axios v1.2.0
It needs to assign Accept-Encoding in axios.get API

```
const axios = require("axios");
async function getData() {
    const resp = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data));
}
getData()
```

Result

```
$ node get-data.js
[{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":
"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}},{"id":2,"name":"Ervin Howell","username":"Antonette","email":"Shanna@melissa.tv","address":{"street":"Victor Plains","suite":"Suite 879","city":"Wisokyburgh","zipcode":"90566-7771","g
eo":{"lat":"-43.9509","lng":"-34.4618"}},"phone":"010-692-6593 x09125","website":"anastasia.net","company":{"name":"Deckow-Crist","catchPhrase":"Proactive didactic contingency","bs":"synergize scalable supply-chains"}},{"id":3,"name":"Clementine Bauch","username":"Samantha","email":"Nathan@ye
senia.net","address":{"street":"Douglas Extension","suite":"Suite 847","city":"McKenziehaven","zipcode":"59590-4157","geo":{"lat":"-68.6102","lng":"-47.0653"}},"phone":"1-463-123-4447","website":"ramiro.info","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Jacobson","catchPhrase":"Face to face bifurcated interf
ace","bs":"e-enable strategic applications"}},{"id":4,"name":"Patricia Lebsack","username":"Karianne","email":"Julianne.OConner@kory.org","address":{"street":"Hoeger Mall","suite":"Apt. 692","city":"South Elvis","zipcode":"53919-4257","geo":{"lat":"29.4572","lng":"-164.2990"}},"phone":"493-17
0-9623 x156","website":"kale.biz","company":{"name":"Robel-Corkery","catchPhrase":"Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity","bs":"transition cutting-edge web services"}},{"id":5,"name":"Chelsey Dietrich","username":"Kamren","email":"Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca","address":{"street":"Skiles Walks
","suite":"Suite 351","city":"Roscoeview","zipcode":"33263","geo":{"lat":"-31.8129","lng":"62.5342"}},"phone":"(254)954-1289","website":"demarco.info","company":{"name":"Keebler LLC","catchPhrase":"User-centric fault-tolerant solution","bs":"revolutionize end-to-end systems"}},{"id":6,"name":
"Mrs. Dennis Schulist","username":"Leopoldo_Corkery","email":"Karley_Dach@jasper.info","address":{"street":"Norberto Crossing","suite":"Apt. 950","city":"South Christy","zipcode":"23505-1337","geo":{"lat":"-71.4197","lng":"71.7478"}},"phone":"1-477-935-8478 x6430","website":"ola.org","company
":{"name":"Considine-Lockman","catchPhrase":"Synchronised bottom-line interface","bs":"e-enable innovative applications"}},{"id":7,"name":"Kurtis Weissnat","username":"Elwyn.Skiles","email":"Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz","address":{"street":"Rex Trail","suite":"Suite 280","city":"Howemouth","zipcod
e":"58804-1099","geo":{"lat":"24.8918","lng":"21.8984"}},"phone":"210.067.6132","website":"elvis.io","company":{"name":"Johns Group","catchPhrase":"Configurable multimedia task-force","bs":"generate enterprise e-tailers"}},{"id":8,"name":"Nicholas Runolfsdottir V","username":"Maxime_Nienow","
email":"Sherwood@rosamond.me","address":{"street":"Ellsworth Summit","suite":"Suite 729","city":"Aliyaview","zipcode":"45169","geo":{"lat":"-14.3990","lng":"-120.7677"}},"phone":"586.493.6943 x140","website":"jacynthe.com","company":{"name":"Abernathy Group","catchPhrase":"Implemented seconda
ry concept","bs":"e-enable extensible e-tailers"}},{"id":9,"name":"Glenna Reichert","username":"Delphine","email":"Chaim_McDermott@dana.io","address":{"street":"Dayna Park","suite":"Suite 449","city":"Bartholomebury","zipcode":"76495-3109","geo":{"lat":"24.6463","lng":"-168.8889"}},"phone":"(
775)976-6794 x41206","website":"conrad.com","company":{"name":"Yost and Sons","catchPhrase":"Switchable contextually-based project","bs":"aggregate real-time technologies"}},{"id":10,"name":"Clementina DuBuque","username":"Moriah.Stanton","email":"Rey.Padberg@karina.biz","address":{"street":"
Kattie Turnpike","suite":"Suite 198","city":"Lebsackbury","zipcode":"31428-2261","geo":{"lat":"-38.2386","lng":"57.2232"}},"phone":"024-648-3804","website":"ambrose.net","company":{"name":"Hoeger LLC","catchPhrase":"Centralized empowering task-force","bs":"target end-to-end models"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity' }
```

add this to your headers should fix it